# Adding users in Azure AD public client app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to enable users logging in through Azure device code flow for a public Azure AD App.

I think the exception I am getting is quite straight-forward:

[image]

In my Azure AD Portal there is no option for adding **Users/Groups** (Azure AD->Enterprise Applications) unlike the Web apps however there is an option to enable **User Assignment**(which is what I want to achieve) which makes it more weird because it says **If this option is set to yes, then users must first be assigned to this application before being able to access it**.

How to assign users to the application if there is no option to do it from the AD portal? [ Azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/methods-for-assigning-users-and-groups#prerequisites) ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1.Navigate to the app registration in the portal -> `Authentication` -> set the `Treat application as a public client` to `No` -> go to the corresponding enterprise application -> `Users and groups` -> add the user -> go back to set the `Treat application as a public client` to `Yes`.

2.You can use the azure powershell [`New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduserapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0) to add the user directly.

Assign a user to an application without roles:

```
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId "<user objectid>" -PrincipalId "<user objectid>" -ResourceId "<service principal objectid(i.e. Enterprise Application objectid)>" -Id ([Guid]::Empty)
```

Assign a user to a specific app role within an application:

```
$username = "<You user's UPN>"
$app_name = "<Your App's display name>"
$app_role_name = "<App role display name>"

# Get the user to assign, and the service principal for the app to assign to
$user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "$username"
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"
$appRole = $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $app_role_name }

#Assign the user to the app role
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id
```

Comment: The 1st option I found out myself that it works but it really is a hack isn't it. Will try 2 as well - thanks for the answer